How to export dynamic symbols only for used functions?
On x86_64 linux, I'm currently using -rdynamic as a linker flag (to gcc) to export used symbols in a program so that I can trace problems when it causes SEGV, or some other places where I output the backtrace using glibc's backtrace(). This program depends on static libraries, which may contain other unused functions which depend on some more static libraries. The program and libraries are built with -ffunction-sections, and the linker has -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed. This combination of flags allows the program to be built without any reference errors.
At least, until binutils-2.22. Suddenly reference errors start to pop up, and I now have to included all those other libraries used in the unused functions. I suppose the linker has started marking every function in an object file as needed when at least one function is referenced. Since other linkers (gold, mold) also show the same behavior, I guess this is the correct™ behavior, and ld.bfd before binutils-2.22 were not working as intended (but working as I intended).
So now, to replicate the pre-2.22 behavior, I guess I have to specify which symbols to export manually, possibly via -W,--dynamic-list. But how do I get the list of used functions?
Minimal reproducible example
main.c
extern int give_747(void);

int main(void) {
    return give_747();
}

lib1.c (unused)
int return_123 (void) {
    return 123;
}

lib2.c
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <backtrace.h>

extern int return_123(void);

static int cb (void *data, uintptr_t pc,
    const char *filename, int lineno, const char *function) {
    printf("%s:%d(%s)[%p]\n", filename, lineno, function, (void*)pc);
}

int give_747(void) {
    void *bt[4] = {0};
    static struct backtrace_state *bts = NULL;

    backtrace(bt, 4);
    printf("backtrace_symbols_fd():\n");
    backtrace_symbols_fd(bt, 4, STDOUT_FILENO);

    printf("\nlibbacktrace:\n");
    bts = backtrace_create_state(NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    backtrace_full(bts, 0, cb, NULL, NULL);
    printf("\n");

    return 747;
}

int return_246(void) {
    int tmp = return_123();
    return tmp+tmp;
}

Makefile
main: main.o lib2.a
        $(CC) -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed $^ -o $@ -L/path/to/libbacktrace/lib -lbacktrace

maindyn: main.o lib2.a
        $(CC) -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -rdynamic $^ -o $@ -L/path/to/libbacktrace/lib -lbacktrace

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -I/path/to/libbacktrace/include -ggdb -O3 -ffunction-sections -c $< -o $@

lib1.a: lib1.o
        ar curs $@ $^

lib2.a: lib2.o
        ar curs $@ $^

Here is the terminal output for the linking of maindyn
cc -Wl,--gc-sections -rdynamic main.o lib2.a -o maindyn -L/path/to/libbacktrace/lib -lbacktrace
lib2.a(lib2.o): In function `return_246':
/home/syukri/playground/gcsections/lib2.c:30: undefined reference to `return_123'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [maindyn] Error 1

※ This sounds like an XY problem, where the actual problem is to produce backtrace with function names, and this -rdynamic shenanigan is just sidetracking. But I need to be able to produce the trace with SEGV, which I currently do by preloading libSegFault.so, but that thing also calls backtrace(). Otherwise, I would have just used libbacktrace.

libSegFault.so is not an enormous library (only 200-some lines), so it kinda feels like you could just fork it and have it call libbacktrace. This has the advantage of giving you traces even for functions that are inlined or otherwise absent from the dynsym table.

@nneonneo Indeed, I was eyeing on replacing libSegFault.so with a modified implementation, possibly based on FreeBSD's one to avoid legal troubles with modifying GNU's version. So that is a good prospect for solving my XY problem for now.

By the way, I tried to find the commit responsible for changing the behaviour you referenced by examining the ld changelogs from 2011 and before (when 2.22 was released - it's old!). However, you didn't specify which version of binutils you upgraded from, so I'm not sure which change was actually responsible. There have indeed been a handful of changes which affect the behaviour of -export-dynamic (the flag which implements GCC's -rdynamic), but nothing which obviously explains what you see.

It was my hope that finding such a commit might explain how to revert to the old behaviour, or at least an explanation of why it was changed. If you want to go down this rabbit hole, you can bisect the binutils version to find the one which introduces the new behaviour, then inspect all the changes in the changelog between those versions.

@nneonneo I actually did bisect binutils, but halfway through the linker kind of stopped working properly, giving out weird errors so I stopped trying.

@nneonneo decided to bisect release tarballs instead, and inspect the diff between the two in the bfd subdirectory. I found the culprit: it was this change in commit 409ff34 that makes -rdynamic apply to symbols even when building executables. I confirmed that removing the extra condtion there makes it work like before again. (Confirmed on ld-2.22 and ld-2.29)

Ordinarily the combination of compile option -ffunction-sections and linkage option gc-sections would make it
simple to obtain a list of the used global functions defined in the program: it would consist simply of the symbols listed as defined global functions
in the global symbol table of the program. Those symbols would not be dynamically exported by default, so the linker
would know that they cannot be referenced from shared libraries. -ffunction-sections causes the compiler
to put each function func in its own linkage section called text.func, and gc-sections causes the linker to
discard each linkage section that it can prove is not used. The linker will then discard all function sections whose eponymous
functions are not referenced within the executable, since they can't be referenced from outside it, and the ones
that survive are the used ones.
But your need for the -rdynamic option frustrates this good work. It causes all global symbols in the executable to be dynamically exported,
making them visible from outside the executable, and thus impossible for the linker to discard. Specifically in your example,
-rdynamic makes return_246 visible, making return_123 callable, forcing you to link lib1.a or have an undefined reference error.
This snag can be dodged by building your program maindyn as per the following makefile.
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: clean

.DEFAULT_GOAL := maindyn 

main-partial.o: main.o lib2.a
    ld -o $@ -r --gc-sections -Map=mapfile $^  --entry=main -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13 -lbacktrace

used_functions.ld: main-partial.o
    echo "{" > $@
    echo $$(readelf -W --syms $< | awk '$$4 == "FUNC" && $$5 == "GLOBAL" && $$6 != "HIDDEN" && $$7 != "UND"' | awk '{print $$NF ";"}') >> $@
    echo "};" >> $@

maindyn: main-partial.o used_functions.ld
    $(CC) -o $@ -Wl,--dynamic-list=used_functions.ld main-partial.o 

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -ggdb -O3 -ffunction-sections -c $< -o $@

lib1.a: lib1.o
    ar curs $@ $^

lib2.a: lib2.o
    ar curs $@ $^
    
clean:
    rm -f maindyn lib1.a lib2.a used_functions.ld *.o

This performs two linkages, excluding lib1.a, without duplication and without coercing the admission of any undefined symbols into the program.
First, it performs a partial linkage (-r), with -gc-sections, that as far as possible completes the linkage of main.o, lib2.a and libbacktrace,
producing the single object file main-partial.o and discards unused sections. We can use gc-sections when producing a partially linked object file as long as we specify
the root symbol relative to which sections must be proved unused, so we specify --entry=main. -Map=mapfile is not needed, but I've
generated the linker mapfile just for its evidence.
Next, the build extracts from main-partial.o the file used_functions.ld which lists, in the format of a linker input -dynamic-list file, all
the symbols which are global functions, defined and not hidden.
Lastly, it performs a full final linkage of maindyn to which the sole specified ELF input is main-partial.o, and to which used_functions.ld
is given as a dynamic exports list, instead of -rdynamic. The executable contains no undefined symbols referenced by unused functions, because -gc-sections
has discarded those from the first partial linkage.
Including libbacktrace in the partial link, rather than the final link, puts the backtrace API into the dynamic exports file, making backtrace() and backtrace_symbols_fd()
visible to their calls from libSegFault.so, which you need.
The build runs like:
$ make
cc -ggdb -O3 -ffunction-sections -c main.c -o main.o
cc -ggdb -O3 -ffunction-sections -c lib2.c -o lib2.o
ar curs lib2.a lib2.o
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
ld -o main-partial.o -r --gc-sections --as-needed main.o lib2.a  --entry=main -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13 -lbacktrace
echo "{" > used_functions.ld
echo $(readelf -W --syms main-partial.o | awk '$4 == "FUNC" && $5 == "GLOBAL" && $7 != "UND"' | awk '{print $NF ";"}') >> used_functions.ld
echo "};" >> used_functions.ld
cc -o maindyn -Wl,--dynamic-list=used_functions.ld main-partial.o

The partial linkage mapfile shows:
...[cut]...
Discarded input sections
...[cut]...
 .text.return_246
                0x0000000000000000       0x14 ./lib2.a(lib2.o)
...[cut]...

Thus return_123 is no longer referenced.
The dynamic exports file is:
$ cat used_functions.ld 
{
backtrace_syminfo_to_full_callback; give_747; backtrace_pcinfo; 
backtrace_alloc; backtrace_vector_release; backtrace_dwarf_add; 
backtrace_syminfo_to_full_error_callback; backtrace_free; 
backtrace_open; backtrace_close; backtrace_vector_grow; 
backtrace_uncompress_zdebug; backtrace_create_state; backtrace_full; 
backtrace_get_view; main; backtrace_initialize; 
backtrace_uncompress_zstd; backtrace_qsort; backtrace_uncompress_lzma; 
backtrace_release_view; backtrace_vector_finish; backtrace_syminfo;
};

And the program runs:
$ ./maindyn 
backtrace_symbols_fd():
./maindyn(give_747+0x36)[0x593768c6c506]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2a1ca)[0x7caea982a1ca]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x8b)[0x7caea982a28b]
./maindyn(+0x2405)[0x593768c5d405]

libbacktrace:
/home/imk/develop/so/scrap1/lib2.c:23(give_747)[0x593768c6c552]

Sidebar
I've left your -as-needed option in place, but when you say:

I suppose the linker has started marking every function in an object file as needed when at least one function is referenced.

I suspect you might be misunderstanding this linker option. It has nothing to do with marking functions needed or not needed. It just tells the
linker not to write a NEEDED libname.so entry into the dynamic section of the output ELF when libname.so is a shared library subsequently input to
the linkage unless the output file references symbols defined in libname.so (i.e. it really needs libname.so). By default the
linker will write such an entry whether symbols in libname.so are referenced or not, possibly leading the dynamic linker to load a
redundant libname.so at runtime. --as-needed remains in effect for ensuing shared libraries until and unless cancelled by --no-as-needed. See man ld.
Linux distros are divided between those that build GCC to preface --as-needed to the boilerplate libraries that it passes to the linker and
those that go with the default. I don't know which sort you have. If it's one that goes with the default then --as-needed may have a desired
pruning effect on the dynamic linkage of your production program and that may be why you've got it, but it has no influence on the linkage
of symbols from object files, including object files that are packaged in static libraries. My Ubuntu system is one of those on which GCC passes --as-needed
in its linker boilerplate. Removing -as-needed has no effect on my maindyn build and you might check if is actually necessary in a production
build based on my solution, if you use it.

Thank you for the thorough answer! I have to admit that I didn't think much when I added --as-needed to the makefile, as this was taken from a larger makefile I am using in my workplace. The answer does give the symbols I wanted. It's unfortunate that we need two linker passes to do this, especially for the C++ programs where linking can take a really long time. But I guess it's unavoidable.

You're welcome :) The time cost of the two linker passes is minimised since the second full linkage does not repeat the symbol resolutions of the initial partial linkage.

This is a hackish workaround, but it might be good enough for debugging purposes:
Add -Wl,-z,lazy -Wl,-z,undefs to your compiler command line. This tells ld to ignore undefined symbols, and additionally enables lazy linking so that the dynamic linker only resolves symbols when they are first used (several distros now default to -z now for security purposes). Since the undefined symbols will never be used, this will be fine. If an undefined symbol is used at run time, you'll get an undefined symbol runtime error. Note that -z lazy has the mild side effect of improving startup performance, at the cost of a security mitigation.
The one downside of this trick is that you won't be warned about any used symbols that are actually undefined due to a programming error. To mitigate this, you could do two link passes: one without -rdynamic and -z undefs to catch undefined symbols, and a second one with both options to create the actual output binary.
